# Activation function for forward propagation

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, softmax

I am building a single layer recurrent neural network and I am training on large sets of pure text (ASCII characters only). I would like to use softmax for the output layer and Tanh for the hidden layer. However, I am not sure where to start to derive the proper activation equations at time step $t$ for the hidden and output layer during forward propagation. For instance, with regards to the softmax, is it $P(y=j|\mathbf {x} )={\frac {e^{\mathbf {x} ^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {w} _{j}}}{\sum _{k=1}^{K}e^{\mathbf {x} ^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {w} _{k}}}}$ or should I be using something different? The reason I don't think it is this equation is because this does not include the time step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the time step you may need the Recurrent Neural Network, and as a simple solution, you can just have the last state information by adding the $\sum u_{jJ}s_{J}(t-1)$ and $\sum v_{ji}x_i(t)$ as the net in the tanh hidden layer.

$s_J(t-1)$ is the Jth neural in the recurrent layer $u_{jJ}$ is its weight between it and the jth neural in the next layer; $x_i$ is the ith neural in the normal input node, and $v_{ji}$ is the weight between it and the ith node in the next layer(the input layer of the softmax).